# Strapi: how to create a new model that belongs to a user?

Tags: api, rest, strapi

I'm just getting started with Strapi.io and I'm currently working on a dummy project to test it out. Note that since I'm using the UI, I don't have any code to share, but I'll try to be as explicit as I can to describe what I want and what I've tried.

I have created a "todo" collection type that has a title, description, category and a user associated with it. The user is a relationship (one user has many todos) to the default user entity created with the Strapi app. When I run `http POST http://localhost:1337/todos "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" title="title" description="description" category="category"` (I'm doing it with Postman) it works, but I see that the `user` field is `null`. I would like it to be automatically assigned based on the user who posted this command. Is that possible to achieve?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible. The way you do this is, you first identify which user actually made this request. This can be done by accessing the `ctx.state.user` variable. This is a global variable set by `Koa` so you can access this in the controller. Now to save the relationship of user against the `todo` collection entry you only need to pass the user id of the user calling this api. This can be retrieved by using `ctx.state.user.id`. So you can use the code below to create a todo collection correctly:

###### Sample code:

```js
await strapi.services.todo.create({
   title: 'My Todo Title',
   description: 'My Description here',
   category: 'Work',
   user: ctx.state.user.id
})
```

**P.S**: You need to make sure **you're logged in and are using a `bearer token`** while calling the api or else, **`ctx.state.user` will be null**.